# How to compute a sine with binary angles?

Tags: geometry, binary-data, trigonometry

How trigonometry works with binary angles ?

Assuming that my 360° or 2pi angle goes from 0 to the maximum value for a given unsigned integer type, how to compute the sin and all the other functions with this representation ?

What is the generic algorithm ?

---

***EDIT***

my point is to drop any floating point computation or floating point type, I would like to implement this with unsigned integers only.

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: @MBo which part is not clear ?

Comment: What do you mean "binary angles"? What value of integer have to match to 2Pi? What's wrong with sin(i*Pi*coeff) etc?

Comment: @MBo binary angles are binary angles, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_angle#Binary_angles . Nothing wrong but all the implementation of sine that I know of are using floating point computation, I'm trying to implement something with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that is your unsigned type goes up to `UINT_MAX`, you mean that 360° stands for the power of two `UINTMAX + 1`.

In this case it is very simple: use the standard-ish trigonometric function `sinpi()` which, when applied to `x`, computes sin(πx).

One example with 32-bit `unsigned int`:

```
sinpi((double)n * 0x1.0p-31)
```

Note that the conversion to `double` and the multiplication are both exact, meaning that the end result is as accurate as `sinpi()` is. You can find a maximally accurate double-precision `sinpi` within [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/).

Comment: can you expand the algorithm a little bit more ? It's possible to keep everything in terms of unsigned integeres ? That's what I'm trying to do . For example just use an `uint32_t` for an angle and any related operation.

Comment: @user2485710 Oh, you are asking how to implement your own sine function. Your question did not make that clear. The good news is that with your choices, the argument reduction is going to be easy. You can even replace the problem of implementing sine near π/2 to the problem of implementing cosine near 0. The bad news is that your question still lacks much of the necessary information that could guide a useful answer. What kind of accuracy are you looking for? Are you already using some sort of system to help you with fixed-point computations or do you expect us to solve that for you? …

Comment: @user2485710 When I say “with your choices”, I mean “with the possible choice that I have decided to assume in my answer”, of course. Your question does not actually say to use UINTMAX + 1 for 360°.

Comment: @user2485710 Lastly, do you expect the result to be an integer too? scaled how? What integer widths should be assumed to be available for intermediate results in order to reach that final precision? If you do not understand these questions, it means the right solution for you is to call `sin()` or `sinpi()`.

Comment: my point is to keep this in the unsigned integers domain, so yes, I expect everything to be an "integer", it should be my new representation for radians and pi. for the widths I would go for 32 and/or 64 bits wide integers, of course I still have to test this so after creating my brand new sine I could tell you more about my preferences, for now I'm ok to accept a solution that converges really fast, my point is to get started with this notations done in unsigned integers .

Comment: @user2485710 Then your question is really about the art of fixed-point computation. It is tedious in general, leading to the quote “It is difficult today to appreciate that probably the biggest problem facing programmers in the early 1950s was scaling numbers so as to achieve acceptable precision from a fixed-point machine” (seen on these slides (the slides are about floating-point): http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/talks/2007/iccmse-2007/ndfpa-slides-handout.pdf ). For just the sake of implementing one sine function, it might be bearable.

Comment: @user2485710 Once you master fixed-point computations, sine() can be implemented with any sequence of argument reduction (easy in your case) and polynomial approximation. That part does not differ much from the implementation of a floating-point sine.

Comment: @user2485710 Get a library! This one even has its own Wikipedia page, hopefully the documentation includes a good tutorial: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libfixmath

Answer (score 1):

I once implemented this, based on a [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) algorithm. For Binary angles, the algorithm is just trivial.

Let a n-bits binary angle and a vector [cos(x), sin(x)] initialized for x = 0. For each bit, from MSB to LSB, just apply a rotation of a fraction of [tau](http://www.tauday.com/) (or pi). Rotation matrices can be precomputed. The algorithm spend at most 4 additions and 2 multiplications, times the numbers of bits set in your binary angle.

However ! the real problem is, how do you represent the resulting values of your sin(x) and cos(x). They can be fixed point, or floats... the main problem being to implement efficiently additions and multiplications for them.